# Export CSV File - JAX RS - REST - AJAX

Tags: java, rest, web-services, csv, jax-rs

I create a function to download a CSV File. I will use that to download simple reports. I got the error below on Netbeans using Wildfly and JAX RS

> RESTEASY002005: Failed executing POST /reports/downloadCSV/: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.io.FileWriter of media type: application/octet-stream

Here is my Code:

**Controller**

**Update on ParametersClass**

```
@POST
@Path("/downloadCSV")
@Produces("application/octet-stream")
public Response downloadCSV(ParametersClass param) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter("MainReport_"+dateFormat.format(date)+".csv");
        fileWriter.append(csvService.mainReport(dateFormat.parse(param.getStartDate()),dateFormat.parse(param.getEndDate())));
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) fileWriter);  
        response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"MainReport_"+dateFormat.format(date)+".csv\"");  
        return response.build();  
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The `csvService` returns a String like:

```
 Column1,column2,column3
 cellInfo1,cellInfo2,cellInfo3
 ,cellInfo2,cellInfo3
 cellInfo1,,cellInfo3
 cellInfo1,cellInfo2,
 ,,cellInfo3
```

I tried using a different `@Produces` => `@Produces('text/csv')` , `@Produces('application/octet-stream')`

If I remove the Annotation `@Produces` I got the following error:

> RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: class com.xo.CSVFile of content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

**AJAX**

```
     var dateRange = new Object();
     dateRange.startDate = '2017-07-20';
     dateRange.endDate = '2017-08-10';
     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: appPath + '/api/reports/downloadCSV/',
          data: JSON.stringify(dateRange),
          async:true,
          success: function(data) {
           }
     });
```

What I'm doing wrong ? Could you help to me please!

.

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to @albert-bos

1st. Check the link in the solution from @albert-bos below.

2nd: Check [this](https://itexpertsconsultant.wordpress.com/2016/08/03/how-to-readwrite-csv-file-to-map-in-java/) link too

3rd:

**Controller:**

```
@POST
@Path("/downloadCSV")
@Produces("text/csv")
public List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> downloadCSV(ParametersClass param) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        return csvService.mainReport(dateFormat.parse(param.getStartDate()),dateFormat.parse(param.getEndDate()));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MessageBodyWriter:**
I create a class called CSVMessageBodyWritter (check the link) but I adpated the method `writeTo`:

```
 @Override
 public void writeTo(Object t, Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
      CsvSchema schema = null;
      CsvSchema.Builder schemaBuilder = CsvSchema.builder();
      if(t!=null){
           List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> reportArray = (List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>) t;
           LinkedHashMap<String, String> headers = reportArray.get(0);

           for (String col : headers.keySet()) {
                 schemaBuilder.addColumn(col);
           }
           schema = schemaBuilder.build().withLineSeparator("\r");
           CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
           mapper.writer(schema).writeValues(entityStream).writeAll(reportArray);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAX-RS only supports a few `Content-Type`s by default (also depending on implementation), like XML and JSON.

The idea of JAX-RS is that it will convert an object to a certain type (e.g. XML or JSON). This is so you can re-use the same object for XML and JSON, without knowing the output in your Controller. Then If you want something different like CSV, you need to define your own `BodyWriter`, see example here: http://www.javaprocess.com/2015/08/a-simple-csv-messagebodywriter-for-jax.html

The problem here is that your controller is to specific for CSV and isn't very flexible. You could put your output of `csvService` into an object and let the `BodyWriter` convert it into CSV.

Comment: Additionally, `FileWriter` isn't a very useful output type for your Response object. FileWriter is for taking bits and writing them to disk; however, it doesn't give your MessageBodyWriter a way to _read_ those bits back off of the disk and into an http output stream. Even though you want your users to download the CSV as a file, it doesn't ever actually need to be a `File` on your server; you'd be okay just putting the String contents of your CSV into the response object.

Comment: Actually the columns are dynamic. Create a class/object with dynamic elements I am not sure how feasible it will be.

Comment: @albert-bos :  THANK YOU TOO MUCH ! It works ! I will update my question to add the adaptation that I used.

Answer (score 2):

### JS

```
window.open("http://localhost:8080/xmlcompare-rs/xmlcompare/excelmisreport");
```

### Rest

```
@GET
@Path("excelmisreport")
@Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
public Response getExcelReport() {
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition",
        "attachment; filename=MISReport.xls");
    return response.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep so can't add a comment for the answer of **Albert Bos**.

There is a **PITFALL** with that solution: you can suddenly run into the problem when you get **empty csv file** even if it should have a data. It happens because of result of **getSize** method.

I'm not sure which version of JAX-RS is supposed to be used in that example (in the article), but accordingly to the [jax-rs documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html#getSize-T-java.lang.Class-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType-), result of getSize is ignored for JAX-RS 2.0, but for JAX-RS 1.X it seems to be used and "return 0" makes downloaded file empty. Make sure you return "-1". I've encountered it when tried to implement csv export in JIRA rest plugin (I guess it's based on first version of JAX-RS).